# Android application on different screen sizes

Tags: android, layout, compatibility

I have an application which works fine on my Galaxy Ace, i mean layout looks fine, all proportional and that stuff. But when I install it on Galaxy Note, it doesn't fit the screen well, i mean it only shows in the top left corner of the screen, and the rest of the screen is white. So I want to know how to adjust it to be same on all screen sizes?

Answer (score 1):

There is a guide in the android developer docu: [Supporting Different Screen Sizes](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are using full values for your views/controls instead of doing it in a density independent way.

Take a look at: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

It explains the several ways to achieve your goals.